# SQL update not accepting alphas

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am new here.
I created a crystal report with an update command (I know, its frowned upon - but I need the multiple values parameter) 
The command has a parameter which is used for the update.
Everything works perfectly when the value I enter for update is numeric. As soon as I add any alpha, I get a 'failed to retrieve data from database' error.
The field its updating is a varchar(100) datatype and the parameter is a string.
I cannot figure out how or what to add to the update statement to allow the alphas. (I'm no expert, but I have experience with SQL views and crystal but not so much the tech stuff) Please help :( :(
Here is my update command - its very simple, and works - for numeric....

```
Update MdnMaster
Set  DispatchComments1 = {?RN}
where (MdnMaster.Invoice in {?Invoice})
```

Thank you

Comment: I assume the parameter cannot be a string, the SQL IN clause expects a list of numbers

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the parameter's value type is string. You can select from String, number etc.. It is correct about the SQL In clause, I have a main report that sorts that bit out, which also works 100%. When the rpt runs, I get my list. The only problem is that it doesn't want to update the field with any alphas. I am not sure whether I have to specify the datatype.

Comment: Note that you get a *failed to retrieve* error, not a *failed to set/update*

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Yes I get a 'failed to retrieve data from database' error. If I put in a alphanumeric, A100 for example. it says A100 is an invalid column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting it to nvarchar?

like this:

```
Update MdnMaster
Set  DispatchComments1 = {?RN}
where (MdnMaster.Invoice in CAST( {?Invoice} AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) )
```

Comment: I was wondering about that, just wasn't sure where and what I had to cast - Ill try it out and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: If it didn't worked, try putting CAST in SELECT statement

Comment: sorry I didn't respond earlier, was hectic with other projects. I have tried both castings, still giving the error. the CAST in SELECT, do I cast those fields I want to update? The field I'm updating is 'DN1' - its already a varchar(100) in the db and works with numbers. its just refusing to accept the alphas.

Comment: Update MdnMaster
  Set  DispatchComments1 = {?RN}
  where MdnMaster.Invoice in (SELECT CAST( {?Invoice} AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) )